# Are in-app purchases marked as such on App Store receipts?

Tags: ios-appstore

I recently got the email from Apple about refunding inadvertent in-app purchases. Instead of going through my purchase history in the slow iTunes app, is there a string I can search for in my email (where all of my receipts are saved) so as to find the receipts that include in-app purchases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching your email for the string: **`In-App Purchase`**

Here's an example email receipt I received from the iTunes App Store which included an in-app purchase (in this case, an X-Men comic from the comiXology app):

[image]